# Scripts are disabled in Bootstrap modal widget

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, yii, modal-dialog

I have a php web project that I used yii framework in..
I have two pages (let's say: index.php, second.php), the first one contains a button witch pops up a bootstrap modal that contains the second page, every thing works fine when I don't use scripts (some jquery) in the second page, but when I do which is my problem, the page loads inside the modal but it's scripts don't work,
what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to listen for [events from the bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage):

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // do something...
})
```